# Nuxt auth SSR cookie issue only when closing browser and loading the page

Tags: authentication, cookies, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I use nuxt and nuxt-auth-next, With a laravel api backend. 
When i completely close browser and load the page nuxt cannot read cookies on `server-side` and wont be able to understand that i am logged in, and on `client-side` it understands that i have cookie so there will be a difference in my `server-side` and `client-side` loading some component based on user being logged in, and then, obviously, this will happen:

```
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

Now when i refresh this page. the problem will go away and everything will be ok.

I also checked if cookies are not availble on `server-side` when loading for the first time:

```
 if (process.client) {
        console.log('cookie = ', this.$cookies.get('auth._token.laravelJWT'));
 } else {
        console.log('cookie = ', this.$cookies.get('auth._token.laravelJWT'));
 }
```

The result on console will be this:

```
Nuxt SSR
cookie = undefined

Client: 
cookie = Bearer blablabla
```

Comment: Having the same issue, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? Please update us.

Answer (score 4):

It's very likely that your cookies are set to **session-only** (default for nuxt auth module), which explains why you face problems after you close the browser. To fix it, given them an **expiration** date, so the server will understand this is an authenticated user.

To expires in 8 days, your `nuxt.config.js` should look like this:

```js
export default {
  ssr: true,
  ...
  auth: {
    cookie: {
      options: {
        expires: 8
      }
    },
    ...
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies :

> Session cookies are deleted when the current session ends. The browser
> defines when the "current session" ends, and some browsers use session
> restoring when restarting, which can cause session cookies to last
> indefinitely long.   Permanent cookies are deleted at a date specified
> by the Expires attribute, or after a period of time specified by the
> Max-Age attribute.

If you use nuxt-auth, and you want to avoid the expiration of the session cookies so the closing browser problem, you can set the expires and maxAge attributes in nuxt.config.js :

```
auth: {
  ...
  cookie: {
    options: {
      expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+20000000000).getTime(), //thats today + a year
      maxAge: 31622400
    }
  }
},
```

this code is from [nuxtServerInit does not receive auth cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013596/nuxtserverinit-does-not-receive-auth-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem while ago.
when your project runs in server side you can access your cookies with this package "cookieparser"

this is the way i get user token in server-side :

```
const cookieparser = process.server ? require('cookieparser') : undefined  


async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {

   if (req.headers.cookie) {
      const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie)

     // if we have a token , get user data with api
     if (parsed.access_token) {
       
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `req.headers.cookie` is `undefined` in my nuxt application. Important is that this is only undefined when i completely close the browser and re open my website. If i refresh the page again the `req.headers.cookie` will become available again!